# How can i rotate smooth the characters back on colliding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    private float degree = 180f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        GameObject character = GameObject.Find(c.name);
        character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, degree), Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I have two ThirdPersonController characters.
When the event OnTriggerEnter is trigger i see in c.Name "ThirdPersonController"

I also added 4 empty gameobjects each one added a box collider set IsTrigger on and also attached each gameobject this script.

And i checked when the character get to the wall they stop moving but keep walking on place.

Now i want at this point that the current character( or both ) that triggered the event to rotate 180 degrees. But instead it's not making rotation the character/s keep walking out of the terrain in some degree changed on the z axis i think.

I guess i did something wrong with the Quaternion.Slerp line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use Collider.gameObject

As you have two gameobjects with the same name, your `GameObject.Find(c.name)` line will always be returning the same one, regardless of which `Collider` actually triggered the collision.

`GameObject.Find` is also very slow in comparison to directly using the gameObject property of `Collider`, so you'll want to avoid using Find as often as possible.

Here's a modified version:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
{
    // Don't use GameObject.Find here - just use the gameObject ref on the given collider:
    GameObject character = c.gameObject;

    character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, degree), Time.deltaTime);
}
```

## Time.deltaTime is for Update only

It's just a fairly random, very small number otherwise.

Comment: Something is wrong. On the 4 empty gameobjects on each one i added a box collider component. If i set the property IsTrigger to ON checkbox is checked when the thirdpersoncontroller is touching the wall(gameobject) he stop moving just keep walking on place. But then it's not triggering the OnTriggerEnter event in the script. If i remove uncheckbox the IsTrigger then it will trigger the event but also then the character will keep walking out of the terrain.

Comment: @DanielHalfoni You'd need to also move the `Quaternion.Slerp` line into `Update` _(because it's using Time.deltaTime, which is incorrect inside OnTriggerEnter)_ but I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to make that the player will not fall and will not walk out of the terrain area that's my general goal in this case.

Comment: @DanielHalfoni Right ok, so you just want the player to instantly rotate - "bounce" off the edge? `Quaternion.Slerp` is the wrong function for that - that's for animating rotations.

Comment: Now it's working. What i did now is made the GameObject character global then in the OnTriggerEnter event assign the Collider c to it. Then in the Update function i moved the line with the  Quaternion.Slerp and also changed the rotation speed by doing 10 * Time.deltaTime now when the player is getting to the wall he turn fast alsmot on place. But as you said in the last comment Quaternion.Slerp is wrong for this use. What should i use then i want to try the right way ?

Comment: @DanielHalfoni if you're animating it then that's fine - that's how it's designed to be used - that previous comment was referring to an instant rotation only.